# Model promise causing template to use .content

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a ember model that has a computed property which is a promise. I am trying to display the resolved value in my template and can only get it working if I do `.content` on the property, which doesn't feel right. Below is my code.
(http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gijozojehe/1/edit?html,js,output)

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [
      this.store.createRecord('foo')
    ];
  }
});

App.FooModel = DS.Model.extend({
  name: Ember.computed(function() {
    return DS.PromiseObject.create({
      promise: Ember.RSVP.resolve('foo')
    });
  }),
  anotherName: Ember.computed(function() {
    return "Hello";
  }),
  otherName: "Hello"
});
```

Template:

```
<ul>
{{#each model as |item|}}
  <li>{{item.name}} {{item.anotherName}} {{item.otherName}}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

I was expecting my use of `DS.PromiseObject` to handle the complexity I am  seeing why isn't it? How can I ensure my template doesn't know that there is a promise backing the value?

Comment: Are you talking about name?

Comment: Yes, I would expect `name` to be able to be used in the template just like `anotherName`. I seem to have to use `{{item.name.content}}` in my template which feels wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The promise object proxies properties on the result of the promise, but the reference to the promise object just returns the promise object.  If you think about references you can see why there is no other workaround for this, even more, the promise object gives you a mechanism for asynchronous activities.

Essentially here's the promise object's get logic:

1. Something requests a property on the promise object
2. If the promise is resolved, grab that property off the content object
3. If it isn't, return undefined

The result of the promise gets placed on the content property, which is how you are able to hack it into working.

To be honest, I'm not positive why you are using Ember Data at all here, you aren't using any of the Ember Data fields etc.  But here's how a promise object (keyword object) was intended to be used.

#### Code

```
user: Ember.computed(function() {
  return DS.PromiseObject.create({
    promise: Ember.RSVP.resolve({name: 'foo'})
  });
}),
```

#### Template

```
{{model.user.name}}
```

Comment: The real scenario is a boolean off of 3 async `.hasMany` relationships that I was able to boil down to this simple string example. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the promise object itself and not the value the promise would resolve to, and that is what is getting printed in your template.

I'm thinking you would return something like this :

return resolve(myPromiseObject);